# how can i make query with couple of profits?

Tags: mysql, sql

first ,i need to get the sum of TotalPrice of sport's and music's departments from the first 3 months of 2016,second, i need to get the result of what i wrote before dividing to sum of all TotalPrice at the year of 2016 from all departments, and third- i need to get the first result dividing to sum of all Total price from all over the years.
all this at the same query!

thanks!

the table called Sales and the attributes are: S_id, date, department, totalPrice.

THIS IS MY CHRY :

```
Select sum(TotalPrice) as sportMusic, sportMusic/sum(TotalPrice)
From Sales
Where (Department="MUSIC" OR Department="SPORT") and
       DATE BETWEEN "2016/01/01" AND "2016/03/31"
```

Comment: Add table definitions, sample table data and the expected result (as formatted text, not images). And also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: Do you have any idea about E/R model ?

Comment: the table called Sales and the attributes are: S_id, date, department, totalPrice.

THIS IS MY CHRY : Select sum(TotalPrice) as sportMusic, sportMusic/sum(TotalPrice)

From Sales
Where (Department="MUSIC" OR Department="SPORT")

       and DATE BETWEEN "2016/01/01" AND "2016/03/31"

Comment: Lack of basic research leads to fear. Fear is the path to the dark side. I sense much fear in you...

Answer (score 0):

You can use your query and two more queries as subqueries (also called "derived tables") in your from clause. Cross join the three result rows and use the totals in your select clause. Something along the lines of:

```
select
  ms_2016_q1.total as   ms_2016_q1_total,
  ms_2016_q1.total / all_2016.total as rate_2016,
  ms_2016_q1.total / all_years.total as rate_all
from
(
  select sum(totalprice) as total
  from sales
  where department in ('MUSIC', 'SPORT')
    and date between date '2016-01-01' and date '2016-03-31'
) ms_2016_q1
cross join
(
  select sum(totalprice) as total
  from sales
  where date between date '2016-01-01' and date '2016-12-31'
) all_2016
cross join
(
  select sum(totalprice) as total
  from sales
) all_years;
```